# How do I solve extra characters in a date format?

Tags: 8, views, datetime

This seems to be a [known issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1538420) in drupal, personal commentary redacted.

So I set up a date format, and any non date-format characters get reprinted at the end of the date.

I first had my formatter set up as `Y年m月`, but read in the issue that I need to escape characters, so:

Format: `Y\年m\月`

Preview in Date and Time preview area: `2016年08月`

Actual output: `2016年08月　年月`

Looking in views where the field is being output (to json in case that makes a difference), there is no custom option for the formatter, so I couldn't try recreating the date formatter in views to see if that would work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the escape characters and then go back in and reassign the format to the type.  Just changing the format didn't solve the problem.